# Обработка и сохранение результатов иерархично связанных выпадающих списков в модальном окне при помощи RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

У меня есть компонент модального окна в котором находится два выпадающих списка (стоит учесть что в будущем их будет 5-6). Эти списки должны быть связанны между собой по иерархии, в том плане что если происходят изменения во втором списке то первый остаётся с тем же значением что и был, но если изменяется первый - **все** последующие списки должны быть сброшены к значению по умолчанию ('All').

Так же при нажатии кнопки **Apply** нужно сохранять выбранные пункты в сервисе, чтобы при следующем открытии этого окна пользователь видел выбранные ранее значения.

NgRx в проекте пока нет и я хочу найти изысканное решение, чтобы когда будут добавляться новые списки не дублировать кучу кода, но пока у меня слишком мало опыта с RxJs.
Вот что я пробовал и не получилось

*hierarchy.service.ts*

```
export interface DropdownOption {
  viewText: string;
  value: any;
}

export interface DropdownOptionGroup {
  groupName: string;
  items: DropdownOption[];
}

export interface HierarchySelectionState {
  bases: DropdownOption;
  points: DropdownOption;
}

@Injectable()
export class HierarchyService {
  public readonly selectedOptions$: BehaviorSubject<HierarchySelectionState> = new BehaviorSubject({
    bases: {
      value: 'all',
      viewText: 'All',
    },
    points: {
      value: 'all',
      viewText: 'All',
    },
  });

  public readonly defaultOption: DropdownOption = {
    value: 'all',
    viewText: 'All',
  };

  private readonly points$: Observable<Point[]> = this.entityDiscoveryService.getPoints();
  private readonly bases$: Observable<Base[]> = this.entityDiscoveryService.getBases();

  constructor(private readonly entityDiscoveryService: EntityDiscoveryService) { }

  public updateSelectedOptions(options: HierarchySelectionState){
    this.selectedOptions$.next(options);
  }
}
```

*hierarchy-modal.component.html*

```
<div class="hierarchy-selection-container">
    <div class="hierarchy-selection-list">
      <div *ngIf="basesOptionGroup$ | async as bases" class="hierarchy-selection-list-item bases.groupName">
        <opp-dropdown [options]="bases.items" [value]="selectedOptions.bases" [disabled]="false"
            (selectionChange)="onDropdownChange($event, bases.groupName)">
        </opp-dropdown>
      </div>

      <div  *ngIf="pointsOptionGroup$ | async as points" class="hierarchy-selection-list-item points.groupName">
        <opp-dropdown [options]="points.items" [value]="selectedOptions.points" [disabled]="false"
            (selectionChange)="onDropdownChange($event, points.groupName)">
        </opp-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-options">
      <button slb-secondary-button (click)="cancel()" class="main-button">Cancel</button>
      <button slb-button (click)="apply()" class="main-button">Apply</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

*hierarchy-modal.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'opp-hierarchy-modal',
  templateUrl: './hierarchy-modal.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HierarchyModalComponent implements OnInit {
  public basesOptionGroup$: Observable<DropdownOptionGroup>;
  public pointsOptionGroup$: Observable<DropdownOptionGroup>;

  public selectedBase$: BehaviorSubject<DropdownOption>;
  public selectedPoint$: BehaviorSubject<DropdownOption>;

  private selectedOptions: HierarchySelectionState = {
    bases: {
      value: 'all',
      viewText: 'All',
    },
    points: {
      value: 'all',
      viewText: 'All',
    },
  };

  constructor(
    public readonly dialogRef: MatDialogRef<HierarchyModalComponent>,
    private readonly hierarchyService: HierarchyService,
  ) {
    this.selectedBase$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.hierarchyService.defaultOption);
    this.selectedPoint$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.hierarchyService.defaultOption);
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.basesOptionGroup$ = this.hierarchyService.getBasessOptionsGroup();
    this.pointsOptionGroup$ = this.hierarchyService.getPointsOptionsGroup();

    this.selectedBase$.subscribe((option: DropdownOption) => {
      this.selectedOptions.bases = option;
    });

    this.selectedPoint$.subscribe((option: DropdownOption) => {
      this.selectedOptions.points = option;
    });
  }

  public onDropdownChange(option: DropdownOption, group: string): void {
    if (group === 'bases') {
      this.selectedBase$.next(option);
      this.selectedPoint$.next(this.hierarchyService.defaultOption);
    } else if (group === 'points') {
      this.selectedPoint$.next(option);
    }
  }

  public apply(): void {
    this.hierarchyService.updateSelectedOptions(this.selectedOptions);
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  public cancel(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с формами в angular в данном примере лучше использовать реактивные формы (`ReactiveFormsModule`).

Мы можем подписаться на изменение необходимого нам контрола и изменять значение другого. Упрощенный пример:

```
  firstControl: FormControl = new FormControl('all');
  secondControl: FormControl = new FormControl('all');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.secondControl.reset('all'))
  }
```

или

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    firstControl: ['all'],
    secondControl: ['all']
  })

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('firstControl')?.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.form.get('secondControl')?.reset('all'))
  }
```